# Select From multi table in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have below tables :

```
branchInfo  (brID, brName)
MotherBoard (ComputerID, Manufacturer, Product, SerialNumber)
Computers   (ComputerID, LatestIP, brID)
CPU         (ComputerID, NumberOfCores, ClockSpeed)
OS          (ComputerID, MemorySize)
Disk        (ComputerID, MemorySize)
Network     (LatestIP, ipSubnet)
```

and want .csv export (brName, Manufacturer, Product, SerialNumber, LatestIP, ipSubnet, NumberOfCores, ClockSpeed, MemorySize, MemorySize) fields
Please help me in writing sql code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is called a join.  You can join multiple tables in SQL by selecting from more than one table at the same time.  When you want to take information out of one table, you have to tell SQL how the tables relate.  As a basic pattern to join two tables, you would tell SQL two tables to select from and then how to join them.  For example, if you have two really simple tables, `dogLicence` and `dogAge` and those tables hold respectively (name, licence number) and (name, age), the code `SELECT * from dogLicence, dogAge` would give you all combinations of dog ages and license numbers.  Therefore, you need the `WHERE` clause.  If you say `SELECT * from dogLicence, dogAge WHERE dogLicence.name = dogAge.name`, you will just select one dog, and you would get its name, license number an age.  Of course it's bad practice to have something like a name as a primary key, but we'll just pretend it is for simplicity's sake.  Finally, you can use a shorthand for a table when you select it.  If you write `SELECT * from dogLicencse s`, you can now refer to that table as 's' in the rest of the statement.  Bearing all that in mind, your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT brname, Manufacturer, Product, SerialNumber, LatestIP, ipSubnet, NumberOfCores, ClockSpeed, MemorySize, MemorySize 
FROM branchInfo br, Motherboard m, Computers c, CPU cpu, OS o, Disk d,     network N 
WHERE b.brID = c.brID 
AND m.ComputerID = c.ComputerID 
AND o.ComputerID = c.ComputerID 
AND d.ComputerID = c.ComputerID 
AND n.ComputerID = c.ComputerID 
and cpu.ComputerID = c.ComputerID 
AND c.LatestIP = n.LatestIP;
```